# wget Will not download a dir that has an index.* file

Tags: linux, recursion, wget

How to recursively get files in a directory if that directory has an index.* file?

I need to copy several directories on different websites located on shared hosting (no SSH) to their new home on a VPS.  Trying to do it server to server.

```
wget -r -e robots=off --no-parent --user=myusername --password=mypass http://mywebsite.com/mydir/
```

This works great retrieving all of the files and sub directories at and below "mydir" with one deal killer of an issue.  If any of the directories has an index.html, index.php etc.  It will not download the contents of that directory.  It will either only download the index.html or if an index.php download it, changing the file to index.html.

I have tried many different combinations of -p -m --no-cookies --ftp flags etc. and nothing gets the directories that have the index.* file.

I'm attempting to get this to work without creating a tar on the source server and downloading it exclusively.

There are vast numbers of articles on SO and other sites about the creation of the index.html file but I could find no info about it skipping a directory if an index file was present.  It would be nice for the copy to not create the index.html but now my main concern is getting the full directory if there is a index.* file.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: @Reeno got me on track.  Re-tried with a fresh FTP account with the following command and all directories including files with index.* can be successfully downloaded now.

```
wget -r --ftp-user=myftpname@mywebsite.com --ftp-password=mypass ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/mydir/
```

Comment: Not possible unless you either know all the filenames in one of these directories or you connect by FTP

Comment: @Reeno I tried wget with ftp earlier but must have missed something.  Created a new FTP account and it worked this time.  Thank you. If you would like to add this as an answer I will be glad to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` never downloads whole directories over http. What you get is that sometimes the webserver allows directories to be represented as a list of its contents. The actual format is a html page so `wget` then recursively fetch whatever the links in that page are pointing at.

If you have ftp access to the site you can use ftp instead. Unlike http ftp is a designed for transferring files from a file system to another. Most ftp clients have the possibility to retrieve whole directories (including subdirectories) without selecting each and every file. There are numerous choices but just putting ftp://your.hostname.com in the location bar of your file manager usually prompts for username and password and you can drag and drop whole directories in most OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing Apache its httpd.conf file. In section  I put an extra X in the 'index' name, as the following:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex indexx.php indexx.php3 indexx.html indexx.htm
</IfModule>
```

Then I restarted the server and tried again. And it worked perfectly.